# AttributeError: module 'graypy' has no attribute 'GELFRabbitHandler'

Tags: django, amqp, gelf

I add LOGGING to my Django project settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'handlers': {
        'graylog_rabbit': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'graypy.GELFRabbitHandler',
            'url': os.getenv('LOG_RABBITMQ_URL'),
            'exchange': os.getenv('LOG_RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE'),
        },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['graylog_rabbit'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
```

and I install these packages in my venv:

```
amqp==5.0.9
amqplib==1.0.2
graypy==2.1.0
graypy[amqp]
```

but this error accured:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graypy.GELFRabbitHandler'
```

I use Pycharm in Windows.

Comment: What Python version did you use, had tried with other?

Comment: @CelioMarcos My python version is 3.9.0